# table is too wide to see in PDF version

Tags: tables

i am new in LYx ...
my tables seem too wide when i compile my document in PDF version.
This is my Source Pane. Kindly help!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c||c||c|}
    \hline 
     & \textbf{Inspiration for new clothes} & \textbf{Purchase clothes/year} & \textbf{Period of year girls spend more on clothing} & \textbf{Priority for clothing} & \textbf{Girls prefer to shop with}\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    \hline 
    \textbf{Maximum} & Style in stores & 50 times & Summer & Quality & Family\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    \hline 
    \textbf{Minimum} & Celebrities & 3 times & Winter & Price & Alone\tabularnewline
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}\protect\caption{Statistical Summaries}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you print on A2-paper? A table with a width of **50cm**????   Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
.................

Comment: No, please put this code in the editor above, where you already have posted the table

Comment: Right click on a column of the table > `More ...` `Configuration` > Set the width of the table and/or the selected column, align, etc. Suggestion: Do ***not*** use spreadsheet-like tables with as many vertical and horizontal rules as possible..

Answer (score 2):

Only a proposition, nothing more, using centered columns with wrapping (`\newcolumntype{C}{...}`)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing 
\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands. %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands. 
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\numberwithin{figure}{section} 
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}} 
\makeatother 

\usepackage{babel}


\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{7}{C{0.12\linewidth}|}}
\hline 
\textbf{Increasing Age Effects} & \textbf{Clothes} & \textbf{Computer Interest} & \textbf{Computer Anxiety} & \textbf{Picky for Food} & \textbf{Motivational Tasks} & \textbf{Kids Interest in Toys}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 & Negative Correlation & Negative Correlation & Positive Correlation &  & Negative Correlation & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Girls} &  &  &  & Positive Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Boys} &  &  &  & Negative Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Girls} &  &  &  &  &  & Negative Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Boys} &  &  &  &  &  & Positive Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular*}\protect\caption{\textbf{Correlation of Age with Different Interests}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not remove the vertical,horizontal lines...

Comment: Kindly if you tell me how i'll edit the source pane.thanks for your patience...

Comment: Faiza: Open your post in the editor window, select the code you want to format with the mouse and either click on the button `{}` or press CTRL - K

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using the `tabularx` environment and the `makecell` package: its `\thead` command allows for a common formatting of column heads and line breaks in cells. Also I replaced the double \hline with an `\hhline`, for which the vertical spacing between the horizontal lines can be adjusted. The caption package allows capton formatting in preamble, and has an `H` option:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = bf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands. %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, tabularx, hhline}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \setlength\doublerulesep{4pt}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{7}{X|}}
    \hline
    \thead{Increasing & & & & & & \\ Age Effects} & \thead{Clothes} & \thead{Computer\\ Interest} & \thead{Computer\\ Anxiety} & \thead{Picky\\ for Food} & \thead{Motivational\\ Tasks} & \thead{Kids Interest\\ in Toys}\tabularnewline
    \hhline{:=:=:=:=:=:=:=:}
                         & Negative Correlation & Negative Correlation & Positive Correlation & & Negative Correlation & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{Young Girls} & & & & Positive Correlation & & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{Young Boys} & & & & Negative Correlation & & \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{Baby Girls} & & & & & & Negative Correlation\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \textbf{Baby Boys} & & & & & & Positive Correlation\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Correlation of Age with Different Interests}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help but the issue i am facing now is that i am not finding how to add code after \use package{babe1} as latek preamble is putting code before babe package which doesnt make any difference in table settings rather extend the whole document. Thanks

Comment: @sound of silence Thanks alot the code worked! Here is my another table, again this is too wide ti fit in a paper, kindly if yiu help me in editing this one.

Comment: \begin{table}[H] \begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c||c||c|} \hline & \textbf{Inspiration for new clothes} & \textbf{Purchase clothes/year} & \textbf{Period of year girls spend more on clothing} & \textbf{Priority for clothing} & \textbf{Girls prefer to shop with}\tabularnewline \hline \hline \textbf{Maximum} & Style in stores & 50 times & Summer & Quality & Family\tabularnewline \hline \hline \textbf{Minimum} & Celebrities & 3 times & Winter & Price & Alone\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}\protect\caption{Statistical Summaries} \end{table}