# how to make changes in table source code

Tags: lyx

I need to make changes in my table source code, source pane is not editable. Kindly anyone tell me how to make changes in table source code.  Your help will be highly appreciated.

See this is my table source code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular*}{50cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{Increasing Age Effects} & \textbf{Clothes} & \textbf{Computer Interest} & \textbf{Computer Anxiety} & \textbf{Picky for Food} & \textbf{Motivational Tasks} & \textbf{Kids Interest in Toys}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 & Negative Correlation & Negative Correlation & Positive Correlation &  & Negative Correlation & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Girls} &  &  &  & Positive Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Boys} &  &  &  & Negative Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Girls} &  &  &  &  &  & Negative Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Boys} &  &  &  &  &  & Positive Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular*}\protect\caption{\textbf{Correlation of Age with Different Interests}}
\end{table}
```

i want to replace it with this code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{7}{C{0.12\linewidth}|}}
\hline 
\textbf{Increasing Age Effects} & \textbf{Clothes} & \textbf{Computer Interest} & \textbf{Computer Anxiety} & \textbf{Picky for Food} & \textbf{Motivational Tasks} & \textbf{Kids Interest in Toys}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 & Negative Correlation & Negative Correlation & Positive Correlation &  & Negative Correlation & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Girls} &  &  &  & Positive Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Young Boys} &  &  &  & Negative Correlation &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Girls} &  &  &  &  &  & Negative Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Baby Boys} &  &  &  &  &  & Positive Correlation\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular*}\protect\caption{\textbf{Correlation of Age with Different Interests}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What kind of changes do you need to make?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is a follup-question of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232205/table-is-too-wide-to-see-in-pdf-version

Comment: Oh yes... i didnt know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the code directly, but you can change the column specifiers to whatever you want. Right click in the table and choose More --> Settings. I guess you will have been here before, to set the width of the table to 50cm.

To set the width to `\linewidth`, select *Line Width %* in the list of units, and set the value to 100. (See screenshot below.)

You cannot, I think, use the `*{<number>}{<col spec>}`, so you would have to do it manually for each column. With the table settings open, click in a cell in the first column. In the field called *LaTeX argument* type `C{0.12\linewidth}`, and click *Apply*. Then, click in a cell in the second column, and repeat. Do the same for all the columns.

[image]

The other option you have is to use an ERT. Copy the `tabularx` environment you have in your question, delete the table in LyX and add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> instead, and use Edit --> Paste special (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the code. (Delete only the tabular itself, not the surrounding float.)

I'm assuming here that you have defined the `C` columntype in the preamble already.

Comment: @faiza Glad it helped. Note that when you get answers that solve your problem, please consider upvoting (clicking the uparrow left of the answer) and/or accepting (clicking the checkmark) the best answer. Accepting an answer marks the question as solved.